# Friendly url with floating count of form parameters

Tags: apache, forms, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, checkbox

I have form with checkboxes. Afrer submit url looks like:
www.site.com?mod[]=1&mod[]=2&mod[]=3
How to rewrite url above (apache mod_rewrite) into:
www.site.com/mod:1,2,3

Big problem is that i don't know how many checkboxes will checked

Comment: Why don't you POST instead of GET?

Comment: You do not know how much `mod[]=` you will get?

Comment: I know max mod[], but i don't how much mod[] will checked by user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just mod_rewrite, I cannot see a way to do this, however, using [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap), you could link to an an external script that would take the query string and return the appropriate new url segments. Then invoke the defined map (program) in your RewriteRule.